How do I pull data into a new list separated by commas
What is a formula to pull the States of overlap in a list separated by commas like in this example?
iXcg.png

Kyle, please note that this site is not a script writing service. Please show the effort you have made to try to solve this problems yourself, the things you've tried, etc, in your questions.

You can use either:
=TEXTJOIN(", ",,FILTER(A6:D6,COUNTIF(A3:H3,A6:D6)))
or for entire rows:
=TEXTJOIN(", ",,FILTER(6:6,COUNTIF(3:3,6:6)))

